# SQL Server : sum by cursor

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2012

This SQL Server 2012 function, and I want it to return all values by the cursor, but this `SUM` only last record from base.

When I want to SUM by:

```
SET @AllSalary = @salarya + @AllSalary
```

it shows NULL.

I don't know what is the problem, it could be syntax error, fact is it doesn't display the desired result.

(`param @montha INT`, will by used later)

```
CREATE FUNCTION allCasR
(
    @montha INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @AllSalary INT;
    DECLARE @salarya FLOAT;
    DECLARE @tymC FLOAT;
    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here

DECLARE kursor_pensja CURSOR FOR
    SELECT contracts.salary
FROM dbo.contracts ;
OPEN kursor_pensja;
FETCH NEXT FROM kursor_pensja INTO @salarya
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
BEGIN
    SET @AllSalary =+ @salarya
FETCH NEXT FROM kursor_pensja INTO @salarya
END
CLOSE kursor_pensja  
DEALLOCATE kursor_pensja
RETURN @AllSalary;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

***WHY*** on earth would you want to use a **cursor** for this??

Just use a `SUM` and since you're seeing `NULL` values, use `ISNULL` to convert `NULL` values into 0 (zero):

```
CREATE FUNCTION allCasR (@montha INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AllSalary INT;

    SELECT @AllSalary = SUM(ISNULL(salary, 0))
    FROM  dbo.Contracts 

    RETURN @AllSalary;
END
```

**Update:** if you **must** use a cursor as an exercise, then you need to make sure

1. that you **properly initialize** your value for `@AllSalary` to `0` (otherwise it's `NULL` from the beginning and will **never** get any other value!)
2. that you take care of the `NULL` values in the database table while iterating over the rows that would cause your entire `SUM` to be `NULL` in the end (either by excluding those values from the cursor with a `WHERE salary IS NOT NULL` or by applying a `ISNULL(....)` to the value being summed up):

Code should be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION allCasR (@montha INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @AllSalary INT;
    DECLARE @salarya FLOAT;
    DECLARE @tymC FLOAT;

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    DECLARE kursor_pensja CURSOR FOR
        SELECT contracts.salary
        FROM dbo.contracts ;

    -- you need to INITIALIZE this value to 0 !!!!! 
    SET @AllSalary = 0;

    OPEN kursor_pensja;
    FETCH NEXT FROM kursor_pensja INTO @salarya

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
    BEGIN
        -- you need to make sure to use ISNULL(.., 0) to avoid a NULL value in the SUM
        SET @AllSalary += ISNULL(@salarya, 0);

        FETCH NEXT FROM kursor_pensja INTO @salarya
    END

    CLOSE kursor_pensja  
    DEALLOCATE kursor_pensja

    RETURN @AllSalary;
END
```

Comment: I know by SELECT is more simply, by that is to school and I must use cursor.

Comment: @user3314502: using a cursor here is totally pointless..... but OK, if it's an exercise: to avoid the `NULL` values, use `SET @AllSalary =+ ISNULL(@salarya, 0)`  to turn any `NULL` values in `@salarya` into `0` so you can sum them up

Comment: But this must only show how use cursor. @marc_s: that`s what you write SUM only last row from database.

Comment: @user3314502: **NO** it will sum **ALL** values from the database!

Answer (score 0):

`SET @AllSalary =+ @salarya`

Your `+` sign is **after** the `=`, that's why it doesn't work as expected.

It should be:

`SET @AllSalary += @salarya;`

**EDIT:**

"That return NULL"

If it returns NULL that means some of your values are `NULL`.

Use `SELECT ISNULL(contracts.salary, 0)` rather than `SELECT contracts.salary`.